# Exception thrown when compiling in 64bit

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have an exception being thrown by a function in a dll; This function should return a char* but fails to do so when I compile with a 64bits compiler from Windows SDK (7.1.7600.0.30514 if that matters)

Everything else in the library works as intented, juste this particular function throws an exception :

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << virtGetErrorMessage(0) << std::endl;
}
```

Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception at 0x5638b861, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at : 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)

When I try to look at what's at the char*'s address in the debugger, all I see is :
@0xffffffffe82a9670 "--- memory read error at address 0xffffffff`e82a9670 ---"

There is no such problem when I use the 32bits version of the compiler :(
I'm using win7 64, qt creator 2.7.1

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a 32bit dll with a 64 bit executable?

Comment: virtGetErrorMessage is not found anywhere on by goole, are you sure it's a legal documented function? And how you know it's okay to call it with 0?

Comment: What output do you get with the 32 bit version?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, I have both the 32bits and the 64bits version of the dll; It is made by a third party so you probably can't find a documentation on the internet. The function converts an error code into a char* message, 0 is a valid error code. The dll is used to communicate with an external device, the error code 0 makes virtGetErrorMessage output something like "Can't connect to device". Thanks for the replies.